# Set multiple objects as datasource of a crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I wanna make a crystal report in my c# windows application, the point is I want to use .net objects as my report datasource, I found its sample code as below in internet and use them and it works fine:

```
        ArrayList Mainlst = new ArrayList();
        Mainlst.Add(new testOBJ { Firstname = "test1", Lastname = "test11" });
        Mainlst.Add(new testOBJ { Firstname = "test2", Lastname = "test21" });
        Mainlst.Add(new testOBJ { Firstname = "test3", Lastname = "test31" });
        Mainlst.Add(new testOBJ { Firstname = "test4", Lastname = "test41" });
        Mainlst.Add(new testOBJ { Firstname = "test5", Lastname = "test51" });
        testCrystalReport rpt = new testCrystalReport ();
        rpt.SetDataSource(Mainlst);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

But I want to send extra object for example school information for these repeated information, but I can't send this extra object, is there any solution that I can send multiple objects to the crystal report? Of course I know that I can use multiple datatable and dataset for a crystal report datasource but here I just want to use objects and IEnumerables as datasource of a crystal report.

Answer (score 27):

if you have many datasource such as 
1.EmployeeClass
2.EmpployeeSkillClass

Do the following :

```
      List<EmployeeClass> employeeList = new List<EmployeeClass>();
      employeeList.Add(new EmployeeClass() { EmpNo = "001", EmpName = "Supitchaya" });

      List<EmpployeeSkillClass> employeeSkillList = new List<EmpployeeSkillClass>();
      detList.Add(new EmpployeeSkillClass() { EmpNo = "001", Skill="C#" });
      detList.Add(new EmpployeeSkillClass() { EmpNo = "001", Skill="Java" });
```

//Create instant of ReportDocument :

```
        ReportDocument report = new RptEmployee(); //Crsytal report file
```

//Set datasource to each table. make sure that index of each table is collect

//(run on debug mode to find that tables[0] map with type Employee or EmployeeSkill)

```
        report.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(employeeList );
        report.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(employeeSkillList );

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

//Finish!!

Comment: I wanted to know if you have an idea why my report is coming up empty

Comment: @Enzero I just saw your question. I think you may have the answer. Sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

When you do this on Design Mode, it tells you that it isn't supported.

Maybe with an Xref between datasources...