# Using Linq and Crystal Reports with .Net Objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, crystal-reports

I am trying to use crystal reports again with Linq but I am having problems. I have read a diverse amount of forums and articles on how this should be done but I am not sure what I could be doing wrong.

**1st Method Tried**

```
Dim DBDataContext = GetDataConnection()

Dim cryRpt As IBS_DAL.cryLocationTransfer = New IBS_DAL.cryLocationTransfer()
cryRpt.Load(cryRpt.FileName)

Dim testDS = From stl In DBDataContext.STranLines
             Where stl.STLStkRef >= "000000000330" AndAlso
                   stl.STLStkRef <= "000000000337" AndAlso
                   (stl.STLTranCode = "LI" Or stl.STLTranCode = "LO")
             Select stl.ToRepObj

cryRpt.SetDataSource(testDS.ToList)

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
```

ToRepObj is currently setting to a class which I made so that it will use a object which doesn't have null value.

But when the report loads it is asking for a password which makes absolutely no sense as I am feeding it the data.The server name is the .net object which I had previously set in the report.

I really need to find a solution as I was previously using Microsoft Reporting but found some areas that are lacking and thus decided that it would be best to use Crystal but have never used it with Linq.

**2nd Method Tried**

I have also tried another way which I have seen on this [website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3861892/696406) but for some reason it is giving me a blank report.The .Net Object are linked on stkcode in crystal report.

```
Dim testDS = (From stl In DBDataContext.STranLines
                 Where stl.STLStkRef >= "000000000330" AndAlso 
                       stl.STLStkRef <= "000000000337" AndAlso
                       (stl.STLTranCode = "LI" Or stl.STLTranCode = "LO")
                 Select stl)
Dim ds1 = (From stl As STranLine In testDS
           Select stl.ToRepObj).ToList
Dim ds2 = (From stl As STranLine In testDS
           Select stl.Stock.ToRepObj).ToList

Dim cryrpt2 As ReportDocument = New IBS_DAL.CrystalReport1()

cryrpt2.Database().Tables("IBS_DAL_roSTranLine").SetDataSource(ds1)
cryrpt2.Database().Tables("IBS_DAL_roStock").SetDataSource(ds2)

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this maybe helpful

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim data As New DataClasses1DataContext
    Dim m = (From master In data.Masters Select master Where master.ID = 10)
    Dim a As New CrystalReport3
    a.SetDataSource(m)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = a
 End Sub
```