# How to display data in crystal report using 2 sql request and 2 datatables in dataset?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a dataset with 2 datatable aand I need to use 2 sql request to display data in crystal report. So I create 2 datatable in my dataset (DataTable1 and dataTable2) I tried this code but it always execute the second sql request!!

```
con.ConnectionString = @"connection";

string sql = "MyRequest1";
string sql1 = "MyRequest2";

DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();  

SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
SqlDataAdapter dad1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, con);

dad.Fill(ds.Tables["DataTable1"]);
dad1.Fill(ds.Tables["DataTable2"]);

CrystalReport1 report = new CrystalReport1();

report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["DataTable2"]);
report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["DataTable1"]);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Are those two tables separate tables in the report? (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910911/set-multiple-objects-as-datasource-of-a-crystal-report/3861892#3861892)

Comment: you can see the solution below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to implement a Datatable Method for each DataTable used in the Dataset: example for the 1st Datatable:

```
protected DataTable DataTable1()
    {
        string sql = "MyRequest";
        SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        dad.Fill(ds.Tables["NameOfDataTable"]);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["NameOfDataTable"];
        return dt;

    }
```

and in the print button you add this code:

```
try {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt1 = DataTable1().Copy(); //the name of the method
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
            CrystalReport1 myreport = new CrystalReport1();
            myreport.SetDataSource(ds);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //code ...
}
```

It works successfully :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to merge the datatables into one and set them. Every time you invoke `SetDataSource` with a datatable, you are overriding the previous data.

Use the `Merge()` functionality to achieve this -

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["DataTable2"];
DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables["DataTable1"];
dt.Merge(dt2);
report.SetDataSource(dt);
```

Comment: @leila.net Updated the answer. Try this out.

Comment: You can see the solution below :)

Comment: thanks @JunaidKirkire, but i tried another solution :)