# Export Crystal Reports with multiple tables in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I am trying to print an orders report from my web application. I have to connect  3 tables to get the data that I want.

For instance, I have an `Orders`, `Contract` and `Products` table. I also have another table `ContractProducts` which is the bridge table for contract and products. The orders table has a customer id as a foreign key and the contract table has a foreign key as well for the customer id.

I actually have a `Customers` table as well but I decided to just use the customer id from the orders table because I have no use for the Customers table. Long story short, I need to display the Order ID, Contract ID and the products associated with the order. I have the following code and it is giving me an error saying that there is an error in retrieving the database. I used the join method however, it is still not working. Please help me. I've spent hours on this :(

//This function is for Export order report

```
public ActionResult CreateOrderReport()
    {
        try
        {              

            var orders = (from o in db.Orders
                     join con in db.Contracts on o.CustomerID equals con.CustomerID
                     join prod in db.ContractProducts on con.ContractID equals prod.ContractID
                     select new
                     {
                         OrderID = o.OrderID.ToString(),
                         CustomerID = o.Customer.CustomerID.ToString(),
                         CustomerName = o.Customer.CustomerName.ToString(),
                         Phone = o.Customer.Phone.ToString(),
                         ProductID = prod.ProductID.ToString(),
                         CategoryID = prod.Product.CategoryID.ToString(),
                         Brand = prod.Product.Brand.ToString(),
                         Volume = prod.Product.Volume.ToString(),
                         PackSize = prod.Product.PackSize.ToString(),
                         Quantity = prod.Quantity.ToString()
                     }).ToList();


            ReportDocument Rep = new ReportDocument();

            Rep.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/OrderReport.rpt")));

            Rep.SetDataSource(orders);
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();

            Stream stream = Rep.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "Orders Report.pdf");
        }
        catch (DataException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: No more details about the database error?

Comment: @JeroenHeier this is the error its giving me...... Error in File OrderReport 5476_25988_{827A9A37-A374-4184-83D7-FB18D2A81587}.rpt:
Failed to retrieve data from the database.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error in File OrderReport 5476_25988_{827A9A37-A374-4184-83D7-FB18D2A81587}.rpt:
Failed to retrieve data from the database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910911/set-multiple-objects-as-datasource-of-a-crystal-report

Answer (score 0):

```
***Replace this part***

********************************************************************

    var orders = (from o in db.Orders
    join con in db.Contracts on o.CustomerID equals con.CustomerID
    join prod in db.ContractProducts on con.ContractID equals prod.ContractID
    select new
    {
     OrderID = o.OrderID.ToString(),
     CustomerID = o.Customer.CustomerID.ToString(),
     CustomerName = o.Customer.CustomerName.ToString(),
    Phone = o.Customer.Phone.ToString(),
     ProductID = prod.ProductID.ToString(),
     CategoryID = prod.Product.CategoryID.ToString(),
     Brand = prod.Product.Brand.ToString(),
     Volume = prod.Product.Volume.ToString(),
     PackSize = prod.Product.PackSize.ToString(),
     Quantity = prod.Quantity.ToString()
    }).ToList();

********************************************************************
***with this***
********************************************************************
db.Orders.Select(p => new
{
    OrderID = o.OrderID.ToString(),
     CustomerID = o.Customer.CustomerID.ToString(),
     CustomerName = o.Customer.CustomerName.ToString(),
     Phone = o.Customer.Phone.ToString(),
     ProductID = prod.ProductID.ToString(),
     CategoryID = prod.Product.CategoryID.ToString(),
     Brand = prod.Product.Brand.ToString(),
     Volume = prod.Product.Volume.ToString(),
     PackSize = prod.Product.PackSize.ToString(),
     Quantity = prod.Quantity.ToString()
}).ToList());
********************************************************************
***and create Dataset with DataTable name is **

> Orderexport

** have this column :***

    OrderID 
    CustomerID 
    CustomerName 
    Phone 
    ProductID 
    CategoryID 
    Brand
    Volume 
    PackSize 
    Quantity


***And change the database source of your Crystal Reports "OrderReport.rpt"***


***

> It works well

***
```